# How to use one event handler fro multiple buttons in Kotlin (I've already seen java with switch statements)

Tags: kotlin

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/firstButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="firstClicked"
        android:text="Color 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.117"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />
```

This is is the code for one button, the other 2 look the same. What I can't seem to achieve is in MainActivity.kt to have only one event handler for all three. I have found java code and can't use it as a guide correctly to transfor it to kotlin successfully, any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the `OnClickListener` interface in your `MainActivity` with a switch statement that could help you identify which button is clicked.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
        Button b2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.b1:
                Intent in = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                SecondActivity.this.startActivity(in);
                break;

            case R.id.b2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Yay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

For kotlin:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btn_start_second.setOnClickListener(this)
        btn_start_toast.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        when (p0?.id) {

            R.id.btn_start_toast -> {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            R.id.btn_start_second -> {
                startSecondApp()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this code but what I'm looking for is a version in Kotlin. Kotlin doesn't use switch as it is rather when()...

Comment: Please check the updated Answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: I'll check it, thanks. One question, I literally started using kotlin yesterday and I'm wondering what does the question mark means after View "View?". If i'm not mistaken View is the type of the parameter.

Comment: Yes. ? denotes whether the variable of type View accepts null value or not. In this case p0, which is of type View can accept null values, which is why we have used safe call parameter ? in when expression.

Comment: When you say btn_start_second.setOnClickListener(this), "this" is referring to the activity?

Comment: Yes, setOnClickListener take objects that implement View.OnClickListener interface , since our Activity has implemented View.OnClickListener, we can pass this  to setOnClickListener